# Detach and serialize doctrine entities

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, entities

My question is referenced to [Doctrine many-to-many relations and onFlush event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180219/doctrine-many-to-many-relations-and-onflush-event)

[image]

Author entitiy: http://pastebin.com/GBCaSA4Z
Book entity: http://pastebin.com/Xb2SEiaQ

I run this code:

```
    $book = new \App\CoreBundle\Entity\Books();
    $book->setTtile('book title: '.uniqid());
    $book->setIsbn('book isbn: '.uniqid());

    $author = new \App\CoreBundle\Entity\Authors();
    $author->setName('author title: '.uniqid());

    $author->addBook($book);

    $entityManager->persist($author);


    $entityManager->flush();
```

In this way all is OK.
Doctrine generate three queries: create author, create book and create links at author_books.

But I need to **detach and serialize** all entities at doctrine **onFlush** event and save them at NoSQL database. And then **other script will unserialize** all these entities and save them to database. And in this way Doctrine generate only two SQL queries: create book and create author. What should I do to doctrine also generate SQL query for linking table?

Here part of the script that unserialize entities:

```
    foreach ($serializedEntities as $serializedEntity)
    {
        $detachedEtity = unserialize($serializedEntity);

        $entity = $entityManager->merge($detachedEtity);

        //$entityManager->persist($entity)

    }

    $entityManager->flush();
```

**UPDATE:** and I  always get error like this:

```
    Notice: Undefined index: 000000002289c17b000000003937ebb0 in /app/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 2776
```

Comment: wow, it seems like a very bad idea. Why don't you implement a higher level service that composes with doctrine orm and nosql/queue, instead of hacking doctrine ?

Comment: this service can implement ObjectManager or extends ObjectManagerDecorator (if you wish). This service would defer persist calls (via serialization if you want).

Comment: But frankly, I don't understand your goal?

Comment: I don't hack doctrine. In any way problem in serialization and deserialization. Is it any way to get all generated SQL queries before they should be executed?

Comment: Yeah I know you don't "hack" doctrine, but you use loosely coupled event driven flow where you need hardly coupled behavior.

Comment: You can have a look at $unitOfWork->getEntityPersister('Class'); that's where is the sql to insert. But not accesible (because it shouldn't).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a behavior of each entity with inherited class like :

```
class FieldRepository extends EntityRepository{
   define all specific methods 
}
```

so each entity will be saved as defined on class

You can use also the helpers concepts, this will solve your problem faster and easy

OnFlush ---> dispache event 'onFlush' --> define behavior on the helper class

Comment: I know about repositories but could you please be more clear. Seems I don't understand you :(

Answer (score 0):

Just a helper class exemple

// Helper book class
       class Booking{

```
      public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->club_interval = $container->get('X.interval');
        $this->security_context = $container->get('security.context');
                                    // your entity manager 
        $this->em = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $this->session = $container->get('session');
        $this->translator = $container->get('translator');
        $this->event_dispatcher = $container->get('event_dispatcher');
        $this->price = 0;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        $this->session->set('booking', serialize($this->booking));
    }

    public function unserialize()
    {
        $b = unserialize($this->session->get('booking'));

        $partner = null;
        foreach ($b->getUsers() as $u) {
            $partner = $this->em->getReference('X:User', $u->getId());;
        }

        $field = $this->em->getReference('X:Field', $b->getField()->getId());
        $user = $this->em->getReference('X:User', $b->getUser()->getId());
        $this->buildBooking($field, $b->getFirstDate(), $b->getEndDate(), $user, $partner, $b->getGuest());
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////      
// here you can choose your database manager check __constructor      
////////////////////////////////////////////
        public function save(){

        $this->em->persist($this->booking);
        $this->em->flush();

        if ($this->booking->getStatus() >= \X\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking::CONFIRMED) {
            $event = new \X\BookingBundle\Event\FilterBookingEvent($this->booking);
            $this->event_dispatcher->dispatch(\X\BookingBundle\Event\Events::onBookingConfirm, $event);
        }

        $this->em->flush();

        return $this->booking;
    }
```

so you can trigger this class method directly form you Symfony2 controller, use save() instead of persist() 
or using event dispatcher but more tricky

```
 if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    $b = $this->get('X_helper.booking');
    $b->unserialize();
    $b->setStatus(\X\BookingBundle\Entity\Booking::PENDING);
    /////////////////////////////////////
    // here use helper's method save instead of flush
    $b->save();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(' route '));
```